# How can I monitor memory usage of a process running from the terminal in OSX

Tags: macos, memory, terminal, osx-mountain-lion

I am running a command line utility called casperJS (installed via node npm) from the OSX terminal. It's a long running process and I'd like to see how much memory it is using, together with any subprocesses.

I don't see the process in Activity Monitor so how I can tell how much memory it is using?

Comment: Look for `phantomjs` or `slimerjs`.

Comment: It should be there but might be under some other name...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Activity Monitor, you can view the list of processes hierarchically, to easily find any processes started from Terminal. Just select *All Processes, Hierarchically* in the toolbar.

[image: Screenshot]

For the tool in question, I'd expect the processes to be called `phantomjs` or `slimerjs` based on the Python launcher.

Answer (score 21):

You can use `ps` for that, for example:

```
ps x -o rss,vsz,command | grep FooProcess
```

then sort by the real memory (resident set) size of the process using (`sort -nr`).

Comment: This will print the memory in MB instead of kb
`ps x -o rss,vsz,command | awk 'NR>1 {$1=int($1/1024)"M"; $2=int($2/1024)"M";}{ print ;}'`

Answer (score 8):

You can use this command for monitoring usage of `PROCESSNAME`:

```bsh
top -l 1 | grep "PROCESSNAME" | awk '{print "MEM="$9 "\tRPRVT="$10}'
```

Comment: He doesn't seem to know the process name. Otherwise it'd show up in Activity Monitor.

Comment: sorry i did not expect that one!

Comment: Version with the name in the front: `top -l 1 | grep "FOO" | awk '{print "NAME="$2 " MEM="$9 "\tRPRVT="$10}'`.

Answer (score -1):

```
top -l 1 | grep -E "^CPU|^Phys"
```

Answer (score -2):

You can run the same program, but forwarding x11.

This means you'll get the physical window open up on your desktop from which you're SSHing in from - It's much nicer in terms of visualisation

Here's a tutorial on how to set up x11. It's really simple to do, and it's much nicer. (plus it's useful for running graphical installer wizards too!)

http://dyhr.com/2009/09/05/how-to-enable-x11-forwarding-with-ssh-on-mac-os-x-leopard/

EDIT: Here's an example I've screenshotted for you of me SSHing in with X11 forwarding(putty) from my Windows machine to my Linux machine, then starting up my system monitor Ksysguard. As you can see the whole window appears as it would do if you were on the actual machine. [image: Capture of SSH and X11]

[image: Image of process manager running via x11]

Comment: can you please mention in your answer if this also works on OSX since the OP asked about OSX specifically?

Comment: Yes it does work!

Comment: I asked that you'll add it in your answer since the original poster asked about OS X specifically.